# How to write a log in system with uniqueness constraint using jdbc

Tags: java, database, jdbc

i want write method for my app when username and email are not unique send massage and take input again .i give constraints unique in my table.

```
 public void signUp() throws SQLException {
    System.out.print("enter your name: ");
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.print("enter your userName: ");
    String userName = input.next();
    String email = "";
    boolean flag1 = true;
    System.out.print("enter your email: ");
    while (flag1) {
        email = input.next();
        if (Validation.validateEmail(email)) {
            flag1 = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("enter valid email");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("enter your password: ");
    String password = "";
    boolean flag = true;
    while (flag) {
        password = input.next();
        if (Validation.isValidPassword(password)) {
            flag = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("please enter valid password");
        }
    }
    User user = new User(name, userName, email, password);
    userRepo.insert(user);
}
```

Comment: Well you're going to have to query the database for those values aren't you?